# How to validate a file path in java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that reads some input from the user which should be a relative path to a predefined folder. For example he will enter test/subfolder and i will generate `/path/to/test/subfolder`.

How can i check for and prevent the user from entering something like `../../../` that will mess up the path and allow him to access path that it's not allowed to?

Comment: You could use [File#getCanonicalFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile()) which will produce an absolute path reference by resolving elements such as /../

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 7+, using `Path` objects, you can invoke the [`normalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize%28%29) method before creating the final path. The method will normalize the path by cancelling out `..` and a preceding path segment and get rid of any `.` segments.

There are a few cases to consider. If the path provided is relative, for example

```
../first/second
```

In this case, the normalization cannot remove the `..` because it doesn't know what would be before it. All you have to do is resolve this path on root `/`. For example

```
Path path = Paths.get("../first");
path = Paths.get("/").resolve(path.normalize()).normalize();
```

The path can have any number of `..` to begin with.

```
Path path = Paths.get("../../../../first/../second/../../more");
path = Paths.get("/").resolve(path.normalize()).normalize();
```

The process will be applied continuously.

There is also the case where the path provided is absolute. In this case, you can simply normalize it right away.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/../../../../first/../second/../../more").normalize();
```

You can then resolve the path provided against your prefix path (careful if the path provided is absolute).

For symbolic links, which others have brought up, continue using NIO with [`java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/LinkOption.html) when using [`java.nio.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: This is not correct. The `normalize` method does not remove all ..'s. It only removes those that are preceded by a directory. E.g., `new File("../../../../a/b/../c").toPath().normalize()` yields `..\..\..\..\a\c`

Comment: @Marwin The solution to that is to resolve relative paths against the root path `/`.

Comment: The root path should work (it was not mentioned when I posted the comment).

Answer (score 1):

To be more consistent, I'd let him write what he wants, and check after he chooses his path if it is allowed (get the chosen File and check its path). He might find a way you didn't think about, for example aliases.

In addition (dispite of that point), if you want the interface to be user friendly and notify it's forbidden already while he is choosing the path, use regular expressions to check if there is a ../ in the entered path (or simply do a `pathString.indexOf( "../" ) == -1` check)

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with exactly this problem before. If you merge the predefined folder with the path using something like

```
new Path(basePath, givenRelativePath);
```

then I do not know of anything other than `..` that would cause the result outside the *baseDir* (providing there are no symlinks pointing outside, of course). Therefore, the simpliest check is to detect the presence of two consecutive dots, just like daniels suggests.

If you want to be absolutely sure (and also handle symlinks or other potentially dangerous things), you may check the result like this (just a sketch):

```
if (givenPath.indexOf("..") >= 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
File result = new File(basePath, givenPath);
if (!result.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(basePath.getCanonicalPath()))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
serveFile(result);
```

This is basically what I ended with a couple of months ago.

Of course, in Java 7+, you may use `Path`s and the `normalize` method instead of `getCanonicalPath`, which is faster and does not touch the filesystem. On the other hand, it does not consider symlinks and other stuff.

Comment: By the way, I am really wondering whether there is anything dangerous beside the two dots (`..`). Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to ignore user inputs, in case of typing relative path in form of '.' or '..',
you could try this one..
[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

```
   File f = new File("/../../../../path/to/folder"); // Wrong user input
   Path path = f.toPath();
   String str1 = path.normalize().toString(); // ouout -> /path/to/folder
```

Comment: This simply does not work. Have you even tried it? str1 will be `../../../../path/to/folder`

Comment: @MArwin yes i have, and the output is just as above. btw i should mention that this solution will not work as described by Sotirios if you have some path like this "/../a/../b/c" so the 'a' part will be cut too.

Comment: Note that it will work with absolute paths, but @Marwin is talking about relative paths.